# What was Jesus' blood type , by official pronouncement of Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, science, eucharistic-miracles

A write-up in cherishrecatholic.org states that Jesus belonged to AB type of blood group, as per official announcement of Catholic Church. The article  cites a eucharistic miracle that happened in Lanciano City, Italy in the 8th century. The Holy Eucharist, preserved since then, was examined by scientists in 1971 who determined the blood type to be AB.

My question therefore is: **Has the Catholic Church officially pronounced that Jesus, in his human body, belonged to certain type of blood group?**

Comment: No, and the Church isn't very likely to do that sort of thing.

Comment: AB+ or AB-? Actual blood type are always given with a + or -

Comment: Also, the Shroud has been tested as well as the veil of Veronica, both supposedly with "AB" blood type. I don't know why a positive or negative was not included from what I recall reading.

Comment: Be positive.    Most liklet

Answer (score 2):

**What was Jesus' blood type , by official pronouncement of Catholic Church?**

Even though the Shroud of Turin and the Eucharistic Miracle of Luciano state the the blood types are similar, the Catholic has not pronounced officially on what blood type was Jesus.

Yet it would seem that the Church is in favour of the opinion that Our Lord had a blood type of AB.

I doubt the Church will ever pronounce anything on this subject matter as it is not part of the deposit of the faith!

> [**How could we possibly know that Jesus blood type is AB?**](https://www.mysticsofthechurch.com/2018/09/jesus-blood-type.html)
>
> However true it may be that we cannot know Jesus blood type for absolute certainty, it seems that God has been pleased to give us a very large body of evidence which overwhelmingly shows Jesus blood type as being AB (most likely AB positive)—evidences such as the Shroud of Turin, the Sudarium of Oveido, along with quite a few important Eucharistic miracles, both historical and also very recent, whose blood test results have all consistently confirmed the AB blood type. In fact, recent scientific blood analysis has confirmed once again the AB blood type in both the Shroud and the Sudarium--two sacred relics which are believed to have physically touched the body of Jesus, and contain His precious blood.
>
> Presented below are just a few of the many cases which having been scientifically tested by laboratories in different areas of the world, all of which reveal the AB blood type:
>
> - The Corporal of Bolsena  (13th century, blood tested in 1995)
> - The Shroud of Turin
> - The Sudarium of Oviedo
> - The Eucharistic Miracle at Lanciano (8th century)
>
> And for those who are interested in more recent events, the three below have occurred in just the last 25 years and the blood results were all type AB positive:
>
> - The Eucharistic host at the Marian Shrine of Finca Betania in Cúa, Venezuela (1991)
> - The (desecrated) Eucharistic host at Buenos Aires,Argentina  (1996) – An interesting side note about this miracle is that the Archbishop who commissioned the investigation was Archbishop Bergoglio - now Pope Francis!
> - The Eucharistic host at the Parish of Saint Martin of Tours in Tixtla, Mexico, (2006)
>
> Each of the links above confirm the AB blood type test result, and as of this writing there is well over a dozen miracles/events which all have resulted in this same conclusion.

Most people believe that Jesus had blood type AB because of the Shroud of Turin. Medically speaking, the AB blood type is now known as the universal receiver; it can take into itself any other type of human blood. There is an important theological message here. Dr. Serafini calls this type of blood the “universal solvent.” That is, it can mix with and dissolve all other types of human blood into itself!

Comment: I realize it's only a metaphor, but it would be much more appropriate the other way, with Jesus able to give to all, while some are not able to receive.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of reported +/- factor might appear unusual because studies pre-1951 repeatedly showed Rh factor negative was unusually low in Jewish groups and ranged from 1.5 to 11%. However a study of 1335 Jews from Jerusalem by [Gurevitch et al (1951) by The Hebrew University-Hadassah Medical School, Jerusalem](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1951.tb02465.x) showed the Rh negative was not unusually low.

However the AB blood group from this study was low at 6.1 to 10.6%, but this is not usually low for a general population. Nevertheless, AB- is a rare blood group in any population.

It is therefore it is difficult to assess the AB blood group information from the blood type of the Shroud of Turin and the Eucharistic Miracle of Luciano. However, there is a high likelihood of AB+ by chance.

---

Genotypic analysis should now be independently performed on both samples and this technology has been available via "DNA fingerprinting" for over three decades. Whole genome sequencing is now the goto technique.